# How to dagger inject a class that require a interface object in its constructor

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a simple Repository class `FoodDataRepository` that only needs a certain `Interface` object in its constructor and I need to inject an instance of `FoodDataRepository` in a `Presenter` class. So far I have done this below but I don't get any crashes but also the injection of `FoodDataRepositor` in the `FoodPresenter` dosn't seem to work or do anything.

**FoodDataRepository.class**

```
public class FoodDatRepository {

public FoodDatRepositoryListener listener;

public FoodDatRepository(final FoodDatRepositoryListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;

    BackendService backendService = BackendServiceFactory.makeBackendService();
    backendService.getFoodData().enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && listener != null) {
                listener.onSetData(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
  }

}
```

**FoodPresenter.class:**

```
public class FoodPresenter implements FoodDatRepositoryListener {


@Inject
FoodDataRepository repository;

public FoodPresenter() {

}


@Override
public void onSetData(Data data) {


   }
}
```

**FoodDataRepositoryModule**

```
@Module
public class FoodDataRepositoryModule {

@Provides
FoodDataRepositoryListener provideListener() {
    return new FoodDataRepositoryListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSetData(Data data) {

        }
    };
}

@Provides
FoodDataRepository provideRepository(FoodDataRepositoryListener listener) {
    return new FoodDataRepository(listener);
}

}
```

**Injector**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    FoodDataRepositoryModule.class
})


public interface Injector {
void inject(FoodPresenter foodPresenter);
}
```

Comment: First of all, is there a reason why you don't want to use constructor injection but do everything yourself? You basically remove most of the benefits Dagger offers by injecting everything manually and calling constructors in modules that you have to declare. As to your problem, are you actually calling `Injector.inject(presenter)` somewhere?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak no `Injector.inject(presenter)` is not called anywhere` but for your information I have set-it up correct in the Application class too. Anyway where should I call `Injector.inject(presenter)`?

Comment: I recommend highly that you spend some more time reading documentation and tutorials to get more familiar wit Dagger. If you _really_ choose to use field injection you have to inject your object before using it. But both, injecting the presenter manually as well as providing your Repository is not necessary if you use Constructor injection.